# How to add dynamic controls to webpage for each user?

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I want to create a webpage that users can create account and there is a common controls and pages like tasks.But users should be able to create their custom controls too.(like buttons, checkboxes, textarea) But of course these custom controls will be specified for only that user.

I created a database table that holds records as ;

```
 user-id -- type -- name -- values

   5  --checkbox -- Is it done ? -- Yes / No
```

Pages gets the controls by reading from database and creates user's custom controls on the page.

So i just don't like this method and i am pretty sure there is a way better solution for this.I am googling last 2 days and just getting more confused.
I can learn new frameworks and languages if there is a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Allowing users create their own forms can get complicated because you'll need to store not only results but the very forms itself, plus the rendering of them. What was helpful for me in the past was using a template engine, that would allow me to write PHP directly, and store it into a new file (e.g. form_customer_1.php). So as the customer creates a form in the database, a new PHP file will be generated for that specific form. This will allow you more control over the in-/output and will (hopefully) be less confusing.